# 14 digit Hex to decimal in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, hexadecimal

I have  14 digit Hexadecimal numbers in Excel which I want to convert to a decimal number.

For example in C2 the number is 0438E96A095180 and that has to be 1188475064373632 in decimal.

I have tried a module in VBA but that is not working:

```
' Force explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

' Convert hex to decimal
' In:   Hex in string format
' Out:  Double
Public Function HexadecimalToDecimal(HexValue As String) As Double

' If hex starts with 0x, replace it with &H to represent Hex that VBA will understand
Dim ModifiedHexValue As String
ModifiedHexValue = Replace(HexValue, "0x", "&H")
HexadecimalToDecimal = CDec(ModifiedHexValue)

End Function
```

With that I get the decimal number 1188475064373630 instead of 1188475064373632.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might use the `CInt` function.

Comment: Thank you AFH, I have made the changes you suggested. Unfortunatly it still does not work. all the last numbers end with a 0 instead of the number it should be.

Comment: Try to use the `variant` datatype instead of `Double`.

Comment: Excel only has 15 digit decimal precision, although VBA can have higher precision using the Decimal datatype.  To return a value with greater than 15 digits, you will need to return a string.  eg: `HexadecimalToDecimal = CStr(CDec(ModifiedHexValue))`.  And you may need to ensure a starting `&H` in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return the value as a string, at least where the result has more than 15 digit precision.

eg:

```
Option Explicit
' Convert hex to decimal
' In:   Hex in string format
' Out:  Decimal in string format
Public Function HexadecimalToDecimal(HexValue As String) As String

' If hex starts with 0x, remove it to represent Hex that VBA will understand
Dim ModifiedHexValue As String

ModifiedHexValue = "&H" & Replace(HexValue, "0x", "")

HexadecimalToDecimal = CDec(ModifiedHexValue)
End Function
```

I will leave it to you to test the length and decide if you want to return a string or a number; and you will note that I modified your `&H` adding routine a bit.